# the differences and relationship between linear independent and affinely independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming

When learning optimization, I heard the two related concepts on linear algebra:

`linearly independent` and `affinely independent`. The definition itself is pretty clear. But how to understand their differences and relationship?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this superficially doesn't appear to be the same notion that is in the wiki on affine independence. Might I ask where you found the definitions? Thanks

Comment: I think I can see how they wind up to be the same in this context, but I'm still just curious about the definition.

Comment: Here is the link for the lecture notes I referred to http://coral.ie.lehigh.edu/~ted/files/ie418/lectures/Lecture3.pdf

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

One difference between an affine space and a vector space is that an affine space does not have an origin point. If you fix one, then you can regard the affine space as a vector space. So in your definition, the additionnal vector $x^1$ can treated as a choice of origin.